Integration of path-dependent submodules in the parent repo
I'm looking to create a (Python) project that contains several (Python) repo.
I felt that the best solution was to use the principle of submodules (with git).
Unfortunately, I'm at a dead end to make this work.
My first repo looks like:
REPO_A  
 - src/  
    - package1/  
       __init__.py 
       file1.py  
    - package2/ 
       __init__.py 
       file2.py 
       file3.py
 - main_file.py 

main_file.py calls file3.py which calls file1.py and file2.py
"main_file > file3 > file1 and file 2"
Everything works as expected in this repo. Imports use an absolute path (such as “from src.package1.file1 import func”).
However, now I would like to integrate this repo in a Parent repo using git-submodule.
The parent Repo looks like:
REPO_B  
 - src/  
    - otherpackage1/  
       __init__.py 
       otherfile1.py  
    - otherpackage2/ 
       __init__.py 
       otherfile2.py 
       otherfile3.py
 - REPO_A
    - src/ ...
    - main_file.py
 - other_main_file.py 

I would like to call functions in the submodule (REPO_A) and here is my issue.
The error returned is:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.package2'".
It seems clear that this path only exists in the submodule, but I don't know how to solve this problem and still have the repo A working alone.
My doubts are:

the location of the sub-module. Is it necessary to put it in a specific place?
Installation. Should this repo be installed as a package or as an alternative? (If so, it would be with poetry).
Use of relative paths. Personally, I don't like this solution.
Adding a path in Python. It's not a clean solution and would be my last resort.

Thanks everyone for your help :)
